# Testing condition between a php form variable and a string?

Tags: php, codeigniter, if-statement

I am trying to test if `$accesslevel` is "admin" or "member", however I seem to have an error in my code. The input of the form is text.

**Here is my control page:**

```
public function addPerson()
    {
      // GET AND SET POSTED DATA
      $username = $this->input->post('username');
      $password = $this->input->post('password');
      $accesslevel = $this->input->post('accesslevel');

      $myerror = "";
      // add the person to database with


        if (($accesslevel != "admin") || ($accesslevel != "member"))
        {
          $myerror = "<br> Access level must be either member or admin.";
        }
        if(strlen($myerror)==0)
        {
          $this->db->query("INSERT INTO usersas6 "."(compid,username,password,accesslevel) VALUES "."(null,'$username', '$password', '$accesslevel')");
          $this->getAllPerson();
          $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
        }
        if(strlen($myerror) != 0){
          $this->TPL["myError"] = $myerror;
          $this->getAllPerson();
          $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
        }
    }
```

I am also getting a warning `(Undefined Variable)` on my view page when I display the contents of `$myError`. How do I properly put `$this->TPL["myError"] =  $myerror;` into an array so that I do not get this warning?

Answer (score 0):

You can edit your code like this, make the $this->TPL["myError"] = $myerror; out side or put it in both statements

```
if (($accesslevel != "admin") || ($accesslevel != "member"))
    {
      $myerror = "<br> Access level must be either member or admin.";
    }     
    $this->TPL["myError"] = $myerror;  
    if(strlen($myerror)==0)
    {
      $this->db->query("INSERT INTO usersas6 "."(compid,username,password,accesslevel) VALUES "."(null,'$username', '$password', '$accesslevel')");
      $this->getAllPerson();
      $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
    }
    else if(strlen($myerror) != 0){
      $this->getAllPerson();
      $this->template->show('Admin', $this->TPL);
    }
```